# Diophantine Equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=c$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> $x^2+y^2+z^2=c$
>
> Find the smallest integer $c$ that gives this equation one solution in
>   natural numbers.
>
> Find the smallest integer $c$ that gives this equation two distinct
>   solutions in natural numbers.
>
> Find the smallest integer $c$ that gives this equation three distinct
>   solutions in natural numbers.

Clearly the first answer is c = 3. I know how to do linear diophantine equations, but I am stumped on this one.

By distinct solutions, I am looking for different threesomes (unordered triples)

Can you help?

Comment: $c=6$ admits $(1,1,2)$ and $(1,2,1)$, but perhaps that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: could this be done using just a computer program?

Comment: You are correct. I am looking for distinct solutions that are different threesomes.

Comment: Put that in the question, then @Goose719

Comment: $c=51$ admits $(1,1,7)$ and $(1,5,5)$.  $c=326$ admits $(1,1,18)$ and $(1,6,17)$ and $(1,10,15)$.  These might not be minimal.

Comment: $c=38$ admits $(6,1,1)$ and $(5,3,2)$

Comment: you are correct $c=27$ yields $(1,1,5)$ and $(3,3,3)$

Comment: $c=54$ admits $(7,2,1), (5,5,2), (6,3,3)$

Answer (score 1):

Since the equation is symmetric: if $(x,y,z)$ is solution than every permutation of$(x,y,z)$ is the solution too. So it's impossible for this equation to have 2 solutions (because if for example $x\neq y$ than we have at least three distinct permutations).
The smallest $c$ for three distinct solutions is $6$: $(2,1,1), (1,2,1), (1,1,2)$.

Comment: OP didn't say it explicitly, but it seems IMO one is looking for distinct solutions where rearrangements are considered the same solution.

Comment: Given the wording, I'd guess that OP means *unordered triples* $(x, y, z)$.

Comment: Sorry didn't know that... For ordered triples this problem is pretty easy :)